# How to do XML POST with FlUrl

Tags: c#, c#-5.0, dotnet-httpclient, flurl

[FlUrl](http://tmenier.github.io/Flurl/fluent-http/) does a great job in dealing with Json/UrlEncoded requests. However, the documentation doesn't really point out how to handle other request types such as `text/xml`.

What's the best way to do an XML POST using FlUrl?

This (accessing underlying `HttpClient`) kinda defeats the purpose of using FlUrl since you need to build the URI and content again:

```
var result = await "http://someUrl"
                   .AppendPathSegment(pathSegment)
                   .SetQueryParam("name", name)
                   .WithBasicAuth(_userName, _apiToken)
                   .HttpClient
                   .PostAsync(<uri>, <content>);
```

Comment: You may also see the https://github.com/milesflavel/Flurl.Http.Soap project for SOAP protocol support.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

XML support is not baked in yet, but this is [logged](https://github.com/tmenier/Flurl/issues/3) and is one of the few remaining features I'd like to have in place for Flurl.Http 1.0. (Surprisingly, no one's requested it until now.)

In the mean time, [Flurl is pretty easy to extend](http://tmenier.github.io/Flurl/extensibility), and you could add this support yourself via extension methods. This should be all you need to post an XML string fluently:

```
public static class FlurlXmlExtensions
{
    // chain off an existing FlurlClient:
    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostXmlAsync(this FlurlClient fc, string xml) {
        try {
            var content = new CapturedStringContent(xml, Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml");
            return await fc.HttpClient.PostAsync(fc.Url, content);
        }
        finally {
            if (AutoDispose)
                Dispose();
        }
    }

    // chain off a Url object:
    public static Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostXmlAsync(this Url url, string xml) {
        return new FlurlClient(url, true).PostXmlAsync(xml);
    }

    // chain off a url string:
    public static Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostXmlAsync(this string url, string xml) {
        return new FlurlClient(url, true).PostXmlAsync(xml);
    }
}
```

---

***UPDATE:***

I decided not to include XML support in Flurl, largely because a community member stepped up and created a great extension library for it:

https://github.com/lvermeulen/Flurl.Http.Xml

Comment: Is there a way to specify a Content-Type of "text/xml" when using this extension library? Out of the box it looks like all requests are tagged with "application/xml".

Comment: @user2710915 `.WithHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml")...`

Answer (score 1):

Digging thru the source, it does seem that a `SendAsync` is work in progress. Since the latest package doesn't support it yet, I thought of adding my own:

```
public static class FlurlHttpExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Sends an asynchronous POST request of specified data (usually an anonymous object or dictionary) formatted as XML.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="client">The FlurlClient</param>
    /// <param name="serializedXml">Data to be serialized and posted.</param>
    /// <returns>A Task whose result is the received HttpResponseMessage.</returns>
    public static Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostXmlAsync(this FlurlClient client, string serializedXml)
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, client.Url.ToString())
        {
            Content = new CapturedStringContent(serializedXml, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml"),
            Method = HttpMethod.Post
        };
        return client.HttpClient.SendAsync(request);
    }
}
```

Yes I took some shortcuts like accepting a serialized XML instead of serializing myself. At the moment, this works for me.

If there's a better approach, I'm all ears!

Comment: Good call on `CapturedStringContent`, I forgot about that. I've found it's well worth the (typically) tiny memory footprint to be able to inspect the original request body afterword if anything goes wrong.

Comment: And yeah, `SendAsync` is sort of a work in progress. It'll change the extensibility  pattern just a little so you won't have to do the try/finally/dispose part yourself. I'll come back and update my answer when that's ready, but it won't cause this implementation to break.

Answer (score 1):

I am a little late to this, however, I have manged to use Flurl nativly, with Xml (had trouble with the xml extension)

First, take your xml data string, convert it to Html content

```
var httpContent = new StringContent(xmlDateString, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");
```

then, use that content in a normal postasync call.

```
var response = await "http://localhost/Notices/webservices/importer.asmx"
        .WithHeader("Authorization", "Basic ssssserrrrr")
        .WithHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml")
        .WithHeader("SOAPAction", "\"http://tempuri.org/ImportData\"")
        .PostAsync(httpContent);
```

In this call, I am setting the content type.  I am also setting the soap action (this is the web method I am calling).

Then it works as normal.

Comment: Do you have to set Content-Type header when the payload is Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml"?

Answer (score 1):

A revision for FlurlRequest

```
public static class FlurlXmlExtensions
{
    // chain off an existing FlurlRequest:
    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostXmlAsync(this IFlurlRequest fr, string xml)
    {
        var content = new CapturedStringContent(xml, Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml");
        return await fr.PostAsync(content);
    }

    // chain off a Url object:
    public static Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostXmlAsync(this Url url, string xml)
    {
        return new FlurlRequest(url.Path).PostXmlAsync(xml);
    }

    // chain off a url string:
    public static Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostXmlAsync(this string url, string xml)
    {
        return new FlurlRequest(url).PostXmlAsync(xml);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For my scenario, I just needed to POST a string representation of my XML while at the same time being able to set the Content-Type to `text/xml` and the encoding to `utf-8`.  Not sure if there is a simpler way to do this I'm just not seeing, but here's an extension method that got me there:

```
public static class FlurlXmlExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Sends an asynchronous POST request that contains an XML string.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="client">The IFlurlClient instance.</param>
        /// <param name="data">Contents of the request body.</param>
        /// <param name="cancellationToken">A cancellation token that can be used by other objects or threads to receive notice of cancellation. Optional.</param>
        /// <param name="completionOption">The HttpCompletionOption used in the request. Optional.</param>
        /// <returns>A Task whose result is the received HttpResponseMessage.</returns>
        public static Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostXmlStringAsync(this IFlurlClient client, string data, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken), HttpCompletionOption completionOption = HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead)
        {
            var content = new CapturedStringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");

            return client.SendAsync(HttpMethod.Post, content: content, cancellationToken: cancellationToken, completionOption: completionOption);
        }

    }
```